# Jboss status from within the container AS 7.1

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I need to constantly monitor the status of the server. The idea that i had was to write a MBean and deploy it as a part of the core services, but what I need is a mechanism (preferably java API) which gives me an interface to constantly keep monitoring the application server status.
Is there a way i can achieve it, twiddle is also an option but that is something that I am not looking at at-least now.

Comment: Can you find something useful in [JBoss AS7 Management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Management+API+reference)

Comment: I can find the management api that will allow me to look up and see the MBeans, what I want is a mbean that will give me a exact status of the servers running in a cluster. The servers are registered under the same jGroups but finding the exact mbean to give me the status is what Iam looking for.

Comment: Did you find some solution to this yet?

Comment: nothing but to use the MXBeans to find the status.